# How can i read the content of a csv file with papaparse ? using react native

Tags: react-native, papaparse

I tried papaparse in order to convert a csv file to json , my problem is that he didn't get the content of the file , it return the uri of file as a string .. Here is my code

```
const   chooseFile  = async() => {
      try {
        const`enter code here` res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
          type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
        });
        Papa.parse(res.uri, {
          complete: function(results) {
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
          }
        }
        )
        console.log(
          res.uri,
          res.type, // mime type
          res.name,
          res.size
        );

      } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
          // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: did u know solution?